# Flex + Air App to Database?

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, livecycle

I'm trying to create the Air app using Flex 4.5. The app interacts with LiveCyle Collaboration Service to support the screen-sharing and webcam chatting in the desktop.

I'm currently looking for the database (not local like SQLite) to store and load the Facebook Wall-sized data. That is, many users can store and load from the database in a short amount of time (synchronization issue). Also, I'll set up the database in Mac mini Snow Leopard server.

I came up with these three solutions:

1) MySQL using AMFPHP - access to MySQL via the server-side language.

2) MySQL via asSQL library - direct access to MySQL, but bad security.

3) BlazeDS/LiveCycleES and ColdFusion - Java EE backend, but ColdFusion is commercial, and suited for the large project?

Which one is the best solution for the small and mid-sized project? or could you recommend any other solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coldfusion is suited for large projects.  It shouldn't matter that it's commercial unless you have a budget that it doesn't fit into.  But, if so then LiveCycleES is much more expensive so if cost is an issue you'll probably have to be use BlazeDS.

As for the "wall-like" feature for Facebook has several things you have to consider.  A wall implies you have some soft of social graph stored.  Graph networks are not very easy to do on a large scale with a relational DB.  I'd suggest looking at a NoSQL storage like MongoDB, Cassandra.  Those options will scale with much less effort than sharding with a database which requires a lot of software engineering just to store everything efficiently.

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2010/05/12/cassandra-by-example/

You're going to have some issues to solve with PHPAMF and BlazeDS if you want to share screens between two clients.  Asynchronous messaging isn't support by either of those options so it's almost a no-starter.  LiveCycle ES has support for this type of thing where Blaze/DS hasn't in the past.  You might want to double check the features of Blaze/DS to see if that's changed lately.  One option you could look at is Red5 which has support for RTMP/E.

http://www.red5.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually, the interaction with LCCS (screen sharing) and the access to the database will be separate to each other. Sorry for the confusion.

The AIR app will just record the file-sharing (via Dropbox) log to the database such as the creation date, the last editing user, and so on. Plus, other users can leave the comment on it, similar to Facebook Wall (each post will be correspond to the file in my AiR app).

Do you still recommend not to use AMFPHP + MySQL? Thanks!

Comment: I would not separate them in that I would not build two separate servers for those accesses. I would have the AIR app to talk LCCS/BlazeDS for everything. Then depending on the method invoked on the controller it can choose to do the screen share via RTMP, or talk to the MYSQL, Cassandra, or whatever your persistence storage you choose. But having one server for this will make simpler to build, test, deploy, and more importantly scale (horizontal). Your server can handled it. I would skip AMFPHP because all that gives you is serialization. The rest is up for you to build, and RTMP is NOT easy.

Comment: Social graphs do not store well to MySQL/Relational when you go into 1M territory. That's why I think you'll find a NoSQL option much simpler.  You can push MySQL/Relational higher, but you have to shard them.  And, that has a lot of engineering cost to invest.  Cassandra can scale horizontally without structuring your data specially as much. But, scaling horizontally with your LCDS/BlazeDS/Red5 server is easy if you use one server that can do all of the features you want.

Comment: Cornel is correct about skill set.  Java has a higher learning than PHP curve so I assume that you know it if you're looking into it.  So I think Cornel's advice is good on this.  Realize if you can stay under a size then mysql will work for you, but realize you might be trapped under a certain scale ala Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose Java/BlazeDS/MySQL as having the best combination between price (free) and reliability (way more people are working with BlazeDS than AMFPHP). NoSQL may sound appealling but all the real projects that'a I'm aware are expensive from a development point of view (teams of 4-8 developers working just on the persistence side). And a relational database like MySQL will handle your scenario quite well. I've configured a system handling 400reqs/seconds using it, without sharding.

On the other hand it's important to match your skills with the chosen stack, your time should be spent working on features, not on learning a new language or a complex framework. If you know PHP way better than Java choose AMFPHP instead of BlazeDS.